# Iterating for loop for list of strings and storing element value

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, iterator

I have a `hashmap` which has a list of keys which i am interating in a `for loop.`
In my Hashmap i have one Key `FURNITURE_NAMES` and values as `Table,Chair,Board.`
Now i want the values that are present in key for `FURNITURE_NAMES` be stored in a list.

Below is the code i have done:

When i get the key `FURNITURE_NAMES` i have the below values

**FURNITURE_NAMES = "table,chair,board"**

```
for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : furnitureMap.entrySet()) 
{
String furnitureKey = entry.getKey();
for(String key : entry.getValue() )
    {   
    if(furnitureKey!=null && furnitureKey.equalsIgnoreCase("FURNITURE_NAMES"))
        {                           
            furnitureList = new ArrayList<String>();
            String a = new String();
            a=key;
            furnitureList.add(a);                                                       
        }
    }
}
```

When i iterate the Hashmap get the key `FURNITURE_NAMES` i get the first value `"Table"`
That value gets stored in the list.
Second i get `chair`.
It overrides value Table and i still have only 1 value in the list that is `chair`.

I tried to put the values in the list through index also but it threw indexoutofboundsexception. How do i have all the values in the list instead of getting overridden by new values. Any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At each iteration you create a new instance of the list as follows:

```
furnitureList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You have to create this list before the for or somewhere else and leave it like that as follows:

```
furnitureList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : furnitureMap.entrySet()) {
// same code here except the list initialization
}
```

Also, you don't need to create a new String for each value. Just put it in the list as the the value variable (which is incorrectly named key :) ) from the for loop. If we refactor your code it would look something like:

```
furnitureList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : furnitureMap.entrySet()) {
    if(entry.getKey() != null && entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("FURNITURE_NAMES")) {
        furnitureList.addAll(entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: There is also an `addAll()` method, which can add all elements from a list. this can replace the inner for loop.

Comment: @TurbutAlin   The method addAll(Collection<? extends String>) in the type List<String> is not applicable for the arguments (String) when i am trying to do addAll

Comment: are you doing `addAll` on the `entry.getValue()` or `entry.getKey()`?

Comment: on the entry.getValue. However when i tried solution of snofty it was working fine. I wanted to implement your solution becaused you have the highest number of votes.

Comment: @NitheshKumar Using add all is no doubt better than adding one value at the time. It is a bit complicated to find the problem since I not know what you did, but you should make sure that the types are matching.

Answer (score 1):

For every iteration you are doing

```
furnitureList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

which is re-initialising your list.

Move it to before your first `for` loop

e.g.

```
furnitureList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : furnitureMap.entrySet())
```

Answer (score -2):

it should be, list should be created before iterating over the map value(ie., list) and creation of string a is not required, it can be directly added to list or you feel to clone try to `String newKey=new String(key);`

```
furnitureList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : furnitureMap.entrySet()) 
{
   String furnitureKey = entry.getKey();

   for(String key : entry.getValue() )
    {
       if(furnitureKey!=null && furnitureKey.equalsIgnoreCase("FURNITURE_NAMES"))
        {                   
          furnitureList.add(key);                                                       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is another key in the `HashMap`, the list will be recreated thus the values deleted.